# How to retrieve and display an image from mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display an image that has been uploaded to mysql database. When i try to retrieve the image, it just displays the filename rather than the actual image itself. Below is the code for uploading image, im not sure if i have done it correctly or included any relevant path of the images. How will i display the image from the database ?

```
<form method = "post" action ="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
 <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
     <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
       </form>



<?php
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpname = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$filesize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$filetype = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$fp = fopen($tmpname, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpname));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`ID`,`name`,`type`,`size`,`content`)
    VALUES( NULL,'$filename', '$filetype', '$filesize', '$content')";

if($mysqli->query($query)){
   echo '<h3>Offer posted</h3>';
} else { 
    echo "error";
}  

?>
```

Comment: you don't show the code where you are displaying the image.

Comment: How will i display the image